# How reorder in between an existing range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting

given scenario,

```
id name sequence
1   a     1
2   b     2
3   c     3
4   d     4
5   e     5
```

User table has `sequence` which represent the order of users to display in the front end.

in the above example if I try to insert a user in between `user id` 3, then the expected behaviour should be

```
id name sequence
1   a     1
2   b     2
3   c     3
4   d     5
5   e     6
6   f     4
```

here position calculated using the last sequence input
`last_sequence = 3.`

Similarly, the user can repeat the same kind of operation, and it should be reordered according to in the database. 
**Note:** not JQuery sorting.

My try

```rb
seq = last_sequence
users.where("last_sequence >= ? and id != ?",3,6).each do |u|
    u.update_attributes(sequence: seq+1 )
    seq = u.sequence + 1
end
```

I know the above is wrong and wrapping my head to find a solution

Comment: Call `User.where('sequence > ?', 3).update_all('sequence = sequence + 1')` to increment all sequence numbers above 3 by 1, then insert the new element at `4`. To remove an element, decrement the following sequence numbers by 1. To move an element, combine the two (delete at old position, insert at new position). Make sure to wrap everything in a transaction. And write tests, it's easy to get a off-by-one error ;-)

Comment: Take a look at http://railscasts.com/episodes/147-sortable-lists-revised?view=asciicast

Comment: @iGian the OP does _not_ want jQuery sorting. (which sorts the list client-side and posts the new order to the server)

Comment: @Stefan, it's not only jQuery, there is a server side, check the controller: `Faq.update_all({position: index+1}, {id: id})`

Comment: Thank u Stefan and @iGian I'm trying your solution...

Comment: Feel free to post an answer if it works

Comment: @iGian well, of course there is server-side code, because jQuery cannot change your database. But the controller code merely stores the provided data. The actual sorting (re-arranging the ids) happens client-side.

Comment: Updating all those records could be a lot of work. If you want to be able to stab out the ith record in the sequence that's one thing, but if you only need to step through the records in sequence there may be an easier solution: replace the sequence field with a linked list, say, `next_id`. Suppose `next_id = 3` for record `7` (i.e., the record with `id = 7`) and a new record  `11` is to be sequenced between records `7` and `3`. Then just set `next_id = 3` for the new record and `next_id = 11` for record `7`. Explaining how you will use the sequence information would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved like the below

```
seq = latest_updated_user.sequence
user.where("sequence >= ? and id != ?",last_user.sequence, last_user.id).order(:sequence, :created_at).each do |v|
  v.update_attributes(sequence: seq)
  seq += 1
end
```